# React Hook useState behavior

Tags: reactjs

I don't quietly undestand when the useState sets initial value. In this code example only on first click props and state values in Table component will be the same. Why they will not be equal on a second/third/fourth click?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.module.css";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState({ bo: false, value: "1" });
  const onClickHanlder = (value: string) => {
    setMode({ bo: true, value });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder("2")}>one</div>
      <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder("3")}>one</div>
      <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder("4")}>one</div>
      <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder("25")}>one</div>
      <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder("6")}>one</div>
      {mode && <Table value={mode.value} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

type TablePropsType = {
  value: string
};
export const Table: React.FC<TablePropsType> = (props) => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(props.value);
  return (
    <div>
      {a}
      {props.value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set the state in Table, only on initial render you give it the default state. If you want them to be the same you have to also have to set the state in Table:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState({bo: false, value: '1'})
    const onClickHanlder = (value: string) => {
        setMode({bo: true, value})
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder('2')}>one</div>
            <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder('3')}>one</div>
            <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder('4')}>one</div>
            <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder('25')}>one</div>
            <div onClick={() => onClickHanlder('6')}>one</div>
            {
                mode && <Table value={mode.value}/>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

type TablePropsType = {
    value: string,
}
export const Table:React.FC<TablePropsType> = (props) => {
    const [a, setA] = useState(props.value)
    useEffect(()=>{
      setA(props.value)
    },[props.value])
    return (
        <div>
            {a}
            {props.value}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This is derived state, don't do this! `a` can be removed entirely since it is `props.value`.

Comment: sure it can be removed, but the question was why it is different from props.value